# Why exactly do the Twin Towers still stand in the Kermit-less world?

Tags: alternate-history, muppets

*[It's a Very Merry Muppet Christmas Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_a_Very_Merry_Muppet_Christmas_Movie)* is about Kermit the Frog exploring a world where he had never been born, *It's a Wonderful Life*-style. It came out in late 2002.

At one point, the Twin Towers are clearly seen in the background of the Kermit-less world.

[image: Muppets Shot]
[image: Twin towers]

They cannot be seen in any of the scenes taking place in the "normal" world.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_entertainment_affected_by_the_September_11_attacks) claims that the the buildings were deliberately added to the film.

Was this just stock footage or footage filmed before 9/11 that unfortunately no one noticed or were the creators seriously claiming that Kermit had something to do with 9/11?  Or is there some other reason?

Comment: Is it clear whether the scenes take place in the alternate present, or could they be showing the history of how things unfolded in a Kermit-less world, in which case that scene could be before 2001? If not, it could also just have been intended as a [butterfly effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect).

Comment: @Hypnosifl It's been a while since I saw the movie, so I'm not sure.

Comment: My comment was deleted. I wonder why.

Comment: Hmm, Kermit responsible for 9-11. I guess he finally snapped on Ms Piggy and that was the result.

Comment: What you're failing to take into account is the instrumental role Kermit played in the creation of the state of Israel.

Comment: The Twin Towers were edited into a great number of movies post 9/11 as a sign of defiance.

Comment: @DeerHunter: Are you saying that a great number of movies were edited, post 9/11, to show the Twin Towers in pre-2001 scenes?  Or are you saying that movies show the Twin Towers in post-2001 scenes (in the real-world timeline)?  Either way, can you name a few?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I asked my good friend Kirk R. Thatcher (the film's Director) this question [on twitter](https://twitter.com/KirkThatcher/status/707932965200728064)

His answer was that the "photo mural" placed in the background was taken before 9/11. The implication is that it was just a simple production error with no conspicuous in-universe reasoning behind it.

[image]

Comment: Seems like something that someone who was in on the conspiracy would say...

Answer (score 3):

Including the twin towers in "alternate reality" footage is commonplace and is usually intended as nothing more than a "cool" nod to "what could have been" and to reaffirm that you're not in your own world any more.

I don't think the writers were suggesting Kermit himself caused 9/11, though there *is* chaos theory to consider after all...

Comment: Although you're not wrong, the OP was clearly looking for a more definitive source of information such as a script note or an interview with someone involved in the making of the film.